# How to solve api response data type aiisgning problem in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The API call was successful but it says:

> Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<List>', but got one of type 'List'

Maybe I am assigning the value that I got in wrong format.

[image]

here is my product controller:

```
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  RxList<WelcomeElement> productList = <WelcomeElement>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future fetchProducts() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var products = await RemoteServices.fetchProduct();
      if (products != null) {
        productList.assignAll(products);
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my remote_service file:

```
class RemoteServices {
  
  static List<WelcomeElement> productList = [];
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<List<WelcomeElement>> fetchProduct() async {
    var response = await client.get("https://steakbox.com/getfood.php",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = json.decode(response.body);
      
      print(jsonString);
      return jsonString;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And please have a look at my model (generated from quictype:

```
List<dynamic> welcomeFromJson(String str) =>
    List<dynamic>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => x));

String welcomeToJson(List<dynamic> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x)));

class WelcomeElement {
  WelcomeElement({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.desc,
    this.typeName,
    this.cookingName,
    this.minPrice,
    this.maxPrice,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String desc;
  String typeName;
  String cookingName;
  double minPrice;
  double maxPrice;

  factory WelcomeElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => WelcomeElement(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        desc: json["desc"],
        typeName: json["type_name"],
        cookingName: json["cooking_name"],
        minPrice: json["minPrice"] == null ? null : json["minPrice"].toDouble(),
        maxPrice: json["maxPrice"] == null ? null : json["maxPrice"].toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "desc": desc,
        "type_name": typeName,
        "cooking_name": cookingName,
        "minPrice": minPrice == null ? null : minPrice,
        "maxPrice": maxPrice == null ? null : maxPrice,
      };
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this exception?

Comment: You can see the error:
` Restarted application in 151ms.
[{id: 18, name: BEEF, desc: Beef description here.., slug: beef, created_at: 2020-12-24 05:17:31, updated_at: 2021-01-13 09:51:01}, {id: 20,
name: LAMB, desc: lamb description, slug: lamb, created_at: 2021-01-02 08:01:23, updated_at: 2021-01-13 09:51:12}]
Error: Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<List<WelcomeElement>>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the value returned by `fetchProduct` method.

```
static Future<List<WelcomeElement>> fetchProduct() async {
...
  var jsonString = json.decode(response.body);
...
  return jsonString;
...
}
```

`json.decode` function doesn't know about the whole of data structure and for that reason it returns `List<dynamic>`, while you are trying to force it to cast it as `List<WelcomeElement>`. You should use `WelcomeElement.fromJson` by each element of `jsonString`.

**Update:** Code inserted.

NetService

```
class NetService {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static Future<T> getJson<T>(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
}
```

Main

```
import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';

class Food {
  int id;
  String name, desc, slug;
  DateTime created_at, updated_at;

  Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = int.tryParse(json['id']);
    name = json['name'];
    desc = json['desc'];
    slug = json['type_name'];
    created_at = DateTime.tryParse(json['created_at']);
    updated_at = DateTime.tryParse(json['updated_at']);
  }
}

class SteakBox {
  List data;

  void fetchFood() async {
    print('Start fetching...');
    data = await NetService.getJson<List>('https://steakbox.com/getfood.php')
      .whenComplete(() => print('Fetching done!'));
  }

  void formatData() {
    if (data != null) {
      foods = <Food>[];
      data.forEach((e) => foods.add(Food.fromJson(e)));
    }
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var steakBox = SteakBox();
  await steakBox.fetchFood();

  print(steakBox.data);

  steakBox.formatData();
  print(steakBox.foods);

}
```

Result

```
Start fetching...
Fetching done!
[{id: 18, name: BEEF, desc: Beef description here.., slug: beef, created_at: 2020-12-24 05:17:31, updated_at: 2021-01-13 09:51:01}, {id: 20, name: LAMB, desc: lamb description, slug: lamb, created_at: 2021-01-02 08:01:23, updated_at: 2021-01-13 09:51:12}]
[Instance of 'Food', Instance of 'Food']
```

Comment: still same issue

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<WelcomeElement> welcomeElementFromJson(String str) => List<WelcomeElement>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => WelcomeElement.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeElementToJson(List<WelcomeElement> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class WelcomeElement {
    WelcomeElement({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.desc,
        this.slug,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
    });

    String id;
    String name;
    String desc;
    String slug;
    DateTime createdAt;
    DateTime updatedAt;

    factory WelcomeElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => WelcomeElement(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        desc: json["desc"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "desc": desc,
        "slug": slug,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

---

```
static List<WelcomeElement> productList = [];
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<List<WelcomeElement>> fetchProduct() async {
    var response = await client.get("https://steakbox.com/getfood.php",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<WelcomeElement> jsonString =welcomeElementFromJson(response.body);
      
      print(jsonString);
      return jsonString;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: recheck my code and change your model class according to it